# How to retrieve coordinates of matplotlib annotate arrow in display space?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to place data at the tip of a matplotlib annotate arrow instead of it's tail. I know this is not the way it is meant to be used. Is there a way to get the coordinates of the arrow tip so that I can place data at that point? I have not been able to figure out how to approach the problem.

My code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, autoscale_on=False, xlim=(120,190), ylim=(190,260))
xy,xytext,col = (130,205),(185,250), 'b'
plt.plot(130,205,'ro')
plt.plot(185,250,'ro')
connectionstyle = "arc,angleA=180,angleB=-180,armA=135,armB=12,rad=2"
plt.annotate('', xy=xy, xycoords='data',
             xytext=xytext, textcoords='data',
             arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-", color=col,
                             shrinkA=0, shrinkB=0,
                             patchA=None, patchB=None,
                             connectionstyle=connectionstyle)
             )
plt.annotate('', xy=xy, xycoords='data',
             xytext=xytext, textcoords='data',
             arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", color=col,
                             shrinkA=0, shrinkB=110,
                             patchA=None, patchB=None,
                             connectionstyle=connectionstyle)
             )
plt.show()
```

NOTE: I need the first annotate to indicate that there is a connection between the two points. I need the arrow to indicate direction of flow. I need to place some text at or near the tip of the arrow to indicate the amount of flow.

How do I get the coordinates of the arrow drawn by the second annotate command?

Comment: You can specify where both ends are in data units.  You can also specify the offset in display space and work through the transformations.  There are several ways to do this, please show a _minimal_ example doing what you are doing.

Comment: @tcaswell I am dealing with a network of points. Offset in display space will be difficult to work with for each connection in a network of connections. My reasoning was that getting the position of the arrows would be easier to manage.

Comment: Would putting the text in the middle be ok? That would be easier to compute.

Comment: @tcaswell yes that would be ok.

Comment: Also look into drawing your second arrow backwards. (On my phone which makes writing a real answer hard)